# no instance of overloaded function getline c++

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused as to what i have incorrect with my script that is causing this error.

I have a function which calls a fill for game settings but it doesn't like my getline.

Also i should mention these are the files i have included for it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;'
```

This is what i have:

```
std::map<string, string> loadSettings(std::string file){

ifstream file(file);
string line;

std::map<string, string> config;

while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    int pos = line.find('=');
    if(pos != string::npos)
    {
        string key = line.substr(0, pos);
        string value = line.substr(pos + 1);
        config[trim(key)] = trim(value);
    }
}
return (config);
}
```

---

The function is called like this from my `main.cpp`

```
 //load settings for game
 std::map<string, string> config = loadSettings("settings.txt");
 //load theme for game
 std::map<string, string> theme = loadSettings("theme.txt");
```

Where did i go wrong ? Please help!

The error:

`settings.h(61): error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::string'`

Comment: and we are talking about std::string here right?

Comment: @BjoernD sorry i thought i had added the error, see edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<string, string> loadSettings(std::string file){
    std::ifstream file(file);
```

File is defined for a `std::string` and a `std::ifstream`, give on a different name.

The error is telling you it can not match the `std::string` to the first param of the `std::getline` function which expects a `std::basic_istream<E,T>`;

EDIT: you should be also try and be more consistant with you `std::` prefixing, string and ifstream are both in the namespace `std::`

Comment: That, and unless he's compiling C++11, he needs to pass `file.c_str()`.

Comment: @jrok I am assuming it is or we would be hearing about that error too.

Comment: So this `loadSettings(std::string file)` needs to be `loadSettings(std::ifstream file)` ?

Comment: @Dave no, do something like `loadSettings(std::string file_path) { std::ifstream file(file_path);`

Comment: `std::map<string, string> loadSettings(std::ifstream dir)`

and 
`ifstream file(dir);` Like that?

Comment: if you like, but `dir` reads like "directory" which is not a file. But it should fix your problem

Comment: @Dave, you have included `<string>` and `<fstream>`?

Comment: no no - the file_path :) also yes i have both included... why?

Comment: I did, theres a waiting time before i can tick it ;)